# Laravel encryp($value) not saved to database

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have the following code in my user model, and $value is encrypted on set, but not saved to the database (MariaDB 10.2 VARCHAR(255) utf8mb4_unicode_ci). When I display the encrypted value and paste it manually to the database, it is decrypted properly. Am I missing something?

```
public function getMyKeyAttribute($value)
{
    if ( $value )
    {
        return Crypt::decrypt($value);
    }
    else
    {
        return $value;
    }
}

public function setMyKeyAttribute($value)
{
    if ( $value )
    {
        return Crypt::encrypt($value);
    }
    else
    {
        return $value;
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
public function update($id, UsersRequest $request)
{       
    $user = \Auth::user();
    $user->update($request->all());

    return redirect('users');
}
```

Request (nothing related to myKey):

```
class UsersRequest extends FormRequest
{

public function authorize() {
    return true;
}

public function rules()
{
        return [
            'name' => 'required'
       ];
}

public function messages()
{
    return [        ];
}


}
```

Comment: Maybe the problem is when you are trying to save(), can you post the code of your controller?

Comment: Controller added. It was working fine before I added the getMyKeyAttribute and setMyKeyAttribute methods to my model, myKey was getting updated, not sure what's going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting an attribute requires you to fill the `attributes` property. The method itself should return a `void`.

```
public function setMyKeyAttribute($value)
{
    if ($value) 
        $this->attributes['my_key'] = Crypt::encrypt($value);
}
```

See https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-mutators#defining-a-mutator for more details.

---

If you're using PHP 7.1, you can use this (will encrypt empty strings but you should check that before setting the attribute):

```
public function setMyKeyAttribute(string $value) : void
{
    $this->attributes['my_key'] = Crypt::encrypt($value);
}
```